# Obtaining the OLS estimators

Tags: statistics, estimation, linear-regression, regression-analysis

So, I'm new to linear regression and this question might be easy, but I didn't find a similar question (one with the same regression model) on the internet.

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent predictors, and that we fit the linear regression model $$E(X_1X_2|X_1,X_2)=a_0+a_1X_1+a_2X
_2$$
using ordinary least squares (OLS). I want to show that the OLS estimators converge to $a_0=-E(X_1)E(X_2)$, $a_1=E(X_2)$ and $a_2=E(X_1)$.

I really don't know how to start. I know I probably have to use this matrix $$
\begin{bmatrix}
    X_{1}^2 & X_{1}X_{2}  \\
    X_{2}X_{1} & X_{2}^2  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I don't even know wich formula I have to use in this case in order to find the OLS estimators. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\mathsf{E}[X_1X_2\mid X_1,X_2]=X_1X_2$.

Comment: Here is one step: the regression plane must contain the mean point, so $E(X_1X_2)=a_0+a_1E(X_1) +a_2E(X_2)$ and by independence  $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$ so $a_0=E(X_1)E(X_2)-a_1E(X_1)-a_2E(X_2)$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. That's a nice way to calculate $a_0$ when $a_1$ and $a_2$ are known, but how do you find $a_1$ and $a_2$?